# MVC - Unable to pass parameter with RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is a method (abbreviated) that looks as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchForCompanies(FormCollection collection)
        {
            CompanySearch search = new CompanySearch();

            search.CompanyList = CompanyData.GetList();

            return this.RedirectToAction("SearchForCompanies", "Company", new {companySearch = search});
        }
```

The method above is redirecting to the method below in the same controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchForCompanies(CompanySearch companySearch)
    {
        if (companySearch == null)
            companySearch = new CompanySearch();

        ...
        ...

        return View(companySearch);
    }
```

On the redirect, the HTTPGet version of SearchForCompanies is getting called successfully. However, the value of the companySearch parameter is always NULL, even though it has a value when the redirect call is made. So I must not be passing the parameter correctly.

Comment: You cannot pass a complex object that way. You could use `return RedirectToAction("SearchForCompanies", "Company", search);` but if any properties of `CompanySearch` contain properties which are complex objects or collections (which it appears to be in your case) it will fail, and there is always the risk of exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception

Comment: Thank you. I should have known that because I've run into this before. If write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass a complex object to an action method, you can use

```
CompanySearch search = new CompanySearch();
return RedirectToAction("SearchForCompanies", "Company", search);
```

which will serialize all the properties of `CompanySearch` to query string parameters. However this will

1. create an ugly url
2. throw an exception is the query string limit is exceeded, and
3. fail if any of the properties of your model are complex objects or
   collection which appears to be the case with your property
   `CompanyList` (the query string become something like
   `...&CompanyList=System.Collections.Generic.List<...>&...`)